# C GZIP get incorrect result

Tags: c, gzip

When I try to gzip a string with C, like

```
    const char *istream = "some me this me";
    uLong srcLen = strlen(istream)+1;      // +1 for the trailing `\0`
    uLong destLen = compressBound(srcLen); // this is how you should estimate size
                                           // needed for the buffer
    printf("estimate size needed for the buffer %d\n",destLen);
    unsigned char* ostream = (unsigned char*)malloc(destLen);
    int res = compress(ostream, &destLen, (const unsigned char *)istream, srcLen);
    // destLen is now the size of actuall buffer needed for compression
    // you don't want to uncompress whole buffer later, just the used part
    printf("actuall buffer needed for compression %d!\n", destLen);
    if(res == Z_BUF_ERROR){
      printf("Buffer was too small!\n");
      return 1;
    }
    if(res ==  Z_MEM_ERROR){
      printf("Not enough memory for compression!\n");
      return 2;
    }
    
     printf("ostream %s\n",ostream);
```

if the input string is a string like "this is...", "some me...." "java va...", the output gzip string I get just have "this" | "some" | "java". So does anyone know what happended?

Comment: I have to get the full gzip string since I want to send it via http post body

Comment: eg. input string is "some me" the output gzip string will be  x\234+\316\317MU, after I decompress this string, I will just get "some", but here I need to get full gzip string...

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding information in comments.

Comment: The C and C++ languages are distinct languages.  Are you mixing them?  Reminder, `std::istream` and `std::ostream` already exist in C++.  You'll also want to use `new` instead of `malloc` and probably `std::string` instead of character arrays.

Comment: The output of gzip compression is binary data, not a null-terminated character string. You can't print it with `%s` format.